# Rails - Stop test environment creating new objects with Obj.find()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the Agile book, and I'm having trouble getting my unit tests to behave. The problem is that two objects are being created during the `rake test:functionals` instead of one. I've identified the reason why but I can't resolve a fix.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(params[:cart])
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart }
        format.json { render json: @cart, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  endnormal
```

and when it redirects to @cart, it calls the application_controller, which contains this code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :the_cart

  private

    def the_cart
      @cart = current_cart
    end

    def current_cart
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
      cart
    end
```

normal
In a development environment, current_cart will not create another cart when session[:cart_id] has a cart already. But in the test environment, simply running Cart.find(session[:cart_id]) creates a newcalls a new Cart item. How do I fix this so that .find doesn't create a new object every time for the test environment?

**EDIT: Here's the test which fails**

```
  test "should create cart" do
    Rails::logger.debug "CREATING CART"
    Rails::logger.debug Cart.all.to_a
    assert_difference('Cart.count') do
      post :create, cart: {  }
      Rails::logger.debug Cart.all.to_a
    end

    assert_redirected_to cart_path(assigns(:cart))
  end
```

Comment: why do you not want it to do that?

Comment: It fails the test. I could make the test check for 2 updated items, but it seems a bit unclean that the supposed function always creates two new cart objects everytime Cart.new is called. How do I make it only create a single object in the test environment?

Comment: You may have to post your test, because two carts should not be being created.

Comment: The test just checks if the number of carts has incremented by 1. However, `Carts.new` creates a Cart in the original `def create` function, and when displaying the html of the page, `Cart.find()` is run from the Applications Controller which creates a second cart.

Comment: I knew there was a reason I didn't like that book. That code doesn't make sense. Why would you have an action to create a cart when every page load will create a cart if you don't already have one? Unless you're supposed to skip that before_filter in your CartsController and you're just not.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't make that much sense, I find it tries to hard to conform to standards. Nonetheless, I would like to know how to prevent these errors in the future when testing, if there is any way to make the Cart.find function work correctly.

Comment: The find function is working exactly as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything that would make tests behave differently, but your code just looks wrong to me.
For each request that comes in, your `before_filter` will load the existing cart and create a new one if non exists.

After your before filter has run, the action will run, which creates a cart without checking for whether one exists, so a second cart is created

Both your before_filter and your create action are creating a cart. The before filter runs first and creates one and then the create action runs and (without checking for the existance of a cart) creates another one.

I'm not sure why you have a `create` action at all if carts get created for you at any point. You could either skip that filter for the create action, or change the create action so that it uses the cart created by that filter (although that would result in a create action that is just an update action, which would be a little odd)

Comment: Hmm, could you explain why the `Cart.create` action is run **after** the before_filter? My understanding is that the `Cart.create` runs first, and then the `before_filter` runs on the page, which should detect that a cart already exists? This is given that `Cart.create` is executed directly from the test which runs `post :create, cart: {  }` right?

Comment: before_filter always run before the action (hence the name). An after_filter runs after the action.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a request spec or integration test, this probably won't create 2 carts as redirects are followed in these kinds of tests properly.  Other tests, test in isolation and my not know about the session variables when set in a test. This was written before seeing the test however.

Are you using fixtures?  Maybe the cart is loaded already. Try adding `pry` to your gem file.  Then in your tests, where the debug statements are put `binding.pry` and you'll get into the test console, and do a `Cart.count` to see how many carts exist.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the test environment to select the cart that already exists?